# How to put an image below the button it is inside

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put this image below its parents button so that the button covers part of the image,   [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuuXp.png), and [not this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgajX.png), so that the bottom of the image pops out under the button.

I've tried using z-index and setting both to relative position, but it seems not to be doing anything even though inspect element shows the z-index of the button as higher than the image.

Here is the html code for the two items. The id is used for hover effects and should be ignored.

```
<a href="film.html">
            <button id="!01Hover" type="button" class="block link">
                <div id="!01HoverChild" class="hoverUp">FILM</div>
                <img src="static/assets/logos/logoHOME1k.webp" id="!01HoverChildLogo" class="navbarLogo" onclick="location.href='./index.html'" alt="Logo">
            </button>
        </a>
```

this is the relevant css for the above code:

```
.block {
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    width: 10.6vw;
    height: 6vw;
    line-height: 1.5vw;
    border: none;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 2.1vw 0vw 2.1vw 0vw;
    font-size: 1.275vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.75s;
    font-weight: bold;
    filter: brightness(100%);
    z-index: 5;
}

.hoverUp{
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.75s;
    transform: translateY(0vw);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.navbarLogo{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0vw 0vw 0vw 0vw;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.75s;
    height:auto; 
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

.link is for the cursor and does not have anything to do with the positioning.

Comment: Please mend your HTML. You may not have a button within an anchor element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position a child element (image) behind its parent (button), the child needs to be absolutely positioned.

```css
button {
  position: relative; 
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
}

.b2 {
  /* partially transparent to expose the image underneath */
  background-color: #333333df;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>FILM</div>
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/250">
</button>

<button class="b2">
  <div>FILM</div>
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/250">
</button>
```

PS. See how much easier it is when you turn your code into a runnable snippet? And the code is the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the point?

Comment: The reason why I included all of the code for the html and css was because of potential conflicts in different styles. I tried adding the above code which did not seem to work, but I soon figured out that the problem was the  filter: brightness(100%); line, which seems to place the object on top when included. Without it, the code works even with relative positioning.

Comment: Great that you've found some answers, but rather than edit my answer, you should post a new answer yourself, and make that the accepted answer.